# PCIe Present pin working principle

Tags: high-speed, pcie

I have a doubt about the PCIe present pin working principle, As shown in the below image which is taken from ***PCI_Express_CEM_r3.0 Specification***, How the Hot-plug control logic will detect the PCIe card lane whether it is x1 or x4, or x8 since its shorted together and connected to Hot-plug control logic.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The number of lanes (and the maximum speed) is detected by trying to use them.

The `PRSNT#` signal only indicates that a card is present and sufficiently far inserted on both ends that all the power supply and signal pins are connected.

This avoids powering up a card that is inserted incorrectly, which may damage the card.